# PHP script to show different array depending on button pressed

Tags: php, arrays, loops, switch-statement, decision-tree

I am writing a PHP script that asks 4 yes/no questions and depending on the answers, displays what animal you are thinking of at the end, it is not finished yet though. I have done the first 3 sets of questions, out of 4 but I don't know how I could display the last set of questions and then the answers without doing about 6 or 7 switch/if statements, is there a better way to do it than this, maybe using some kind of loop? Below is code I written so far and you can view the quiz at http://s504518.brunelweb.net/Creatures.php although its not finished yet. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(2592000); //Sets cookie to last for 30 days
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Creature Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Creature Guessing Game</h1>
<p> Welcome to the creature guessing game! </p>
<p>Click the button below to start or restart the game </p>

<form method="post" action="Creatures.php">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="Start Game" />
</form>
 <?php
 $firstquestion = "Does the creature live on the land?"; //Question 1

 $questions = array( //Question 2   //Question 3
    array('Does it have wings?', 'Is it amphibious?'), //First answer is for yes, second for no

        //Question 4    //Question 5     //Question 6       //Question 7
    array('Can it fly?', 'Is it an insect?', 'Is it white?', 'Does it have tentacles?'), //First 2 are yes/no for Q2 and second 2 are yes/no for Q3

            //Question 8    //Question 9       //Question 10    //Question 11
    array('Is it brown?','Does it live in Australia?','Is it green?','Does it have 2 arms?'), //First 2 are yes/no for Q4, second 2 are yes/no for Q5

        //Question 12           //Question 13           //Question 14           //Question 15
    array('Does it live in the Artic?','Do they eat their legs in France?','Has is got eight of them?','Can you keep them as pets?')
    //First 2 are yes/no for Q6 and second 2 are yes/no for Q7
            );

 $answers1 = array('Eagle','Parrot','Ostrich','Turkey','Grasshopper','Ant','Gorilla','Tiger'); //Answers is Q1 is yes

 $answer2 = array('Penguin','Goose','Frog','Salamander','Octopus','Jellyfish','Goldfish','Eel'); //Answers is Q1 is no

 $number;
  function showquestion($number) {
      echo "<form method ='post' action='Creatures.php'>
     <input type='submit' name='answer$number' value='Yes' />
     <input type='submit' name='answer$number' value='No' />
     </form>";
 }
//If form not submitted, display form.
if (!isset($_POST['start'])){
?>
<?php
} //If form is submitted, process input
else{ 
echo $firstquestion;
     echo "<form method ='post' action='Creatures.php'>
     <input type='submit' name='yes1' value='Yes' />
     <input type='submit' name='no1' value='No' />
     </form>";
}
if ($_POST['yes1']) //If answer to Q1 is yes then display this
{
echo $questions[0][0];
showquestion(1);
}

if ($_POST['no1']) 
{
echo $questions[0][1]; //If answer to Q1 is no then display this
showquestion(2);
}

switch($_POST['answer1']) //Q2 - Show the next question depending on the button pressed
{
case 'Yes': echo $questions[1][0]; showquestion(3);
break;
case 'No': echo $questions[1][1]; showquestion(4);
}

switch($_POST['answer2']) //Q3 - Show the next question depending on the button pressed
{
case 'Yes': echo $questions[1][2]; showquestion(5);
break;
case 'No': echo $questions[1][3]; showquestion(6);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should create a chain to next question based on the answer of the previous question. First you should draw some tree structure on a paper showing the flow of questions based on the previous answer. Once it is clear then only it is possible to implement.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do but don't know how, I already have a tree structure on paper and I know what where each question should go and what the answer will be at the end, but don't know how to implement this in PHP, how would I create the chain of questions?

Comment: Can you put your sample tree structure atleat for 3 questions ? A diagram will be good. Its intereseting....

Comment: It needs to be at least 4 questions long because there needs to be at least 16 possible answers. My diagram looks similar to this one - http://www.intechopen.com/source/html/10957/media/image2.jpg but with another 2 branches coming off each block at the end.

Comment: As per that diagram, is there any case Q3 can come if Q1 is Yes and Q2 is No?

Comment: No the only way to get to Q3 is by answering No to Q1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using arrays, what I ll suggest is create following tables

Questions Table

```
QId,Question
```

Quesiton Options Table

```
Qid, AID, Answer Description
```

QuestionsFlow Table

```
QId, AID, QID
```

When a question is answered for a particular question you can fecth the next question based on the question ID and answer ID. It will be simple to add new questions / alter your flow of questions also. For eg as per your diagram the QuesitonsFlow table will be like this

```
QID | AnsID | NextQID
1   | 1     |  2
1   | 2     | 3
```

This way you can extend your table.

Comment: I haven't used tables before in PHP, how do you create tables in PHP?

Comment: Well you need to choose database like mysql or sqlite or anything. Using arrays also it can be done, but it will be bit difficult from the point of code maintainability or If you know xml, you can store that data in xml also.

Comment: Well I only know a little bit of mysql as I am still learning, will try it with arrays.